# Is the WHO tetanus vaccination campaign a covert sterilisation campaign?

Tags: vaccines

Lifesite News (a Canadian conservative Christian pro-life [news source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Campaign_Life_Coalition)) [reports](https://www.lifesitenews.com/news/a-mass-sterilization-exercise-kenyan-doctors-find-anti-fertility-agent-in-u):

> But it is the five-vaccination regime that is most alarming.
>
> > “The only time tetanus vaccine has been given in five doses is when it is used as a carrier in fertility regulating vaccines laced with the pregnancy hormone, Human Chorionic Gonadotropin (HCG) developed by WHO in 1992.”
>
> It is HCG that has been found in all six samples sent to the University of Nairobi medical laboratory and another in South Africa. The bishops and doctors warn that injecting women with HCG , which mimics a natural hormone produced by pregnant women, causes them to develop antibodies against it. When they do get pregnant, and produce their own version of HCG, it triggers the production of antibodies that cause a miscarriage.
>
> > “We knew that the last time this vaccination with five injections has been used was in Mexico in 1993 and Nicaragua and the Philippines in 1994,”
>
> said Dr. Ngare.
>
> > “It didn’t cause miscarriages till three years later,”
>
> which is why, he added, the counterclaims that women who got the vaccination recently and then got pregnant are meaningless.
>
> Ngare said WHO tried to bring the same anti-fertility program into Kenya in the 1990s.
>
> > “We alerted the government and it stopped the vaccination. But this time they haven’t done so.”

This was even followed up by: 
John W. Oller … Wahome Ngare et al.: ["HCG Found in WHO Tetanus Vaccine in Kenya Raises Concern in the Developing World"](https://www.scirp.org/html/81838_81838.htm), Open Access Library Journal, Vol.04 No.10 (2017), Article ID:81838, 10.4236/oalib.1103937

Is a World Health Organisation (WHO) tetanus vaccination campaign in Africa actually a covert sterilisation campaign?

If that's not answerable yet, then alternatively what evidence is for historical and/or circumstantial claims:

- Explaining the history of using HCG in vaccines to prevent pregnancy
- Confirming whether the WHO (or any similar organization) has ever done this (used HCG in vaccines to prevent pregnancy) surreptitiously, whether accidentally or deliberately, in the past?
- Confirming whether it's true that the current program in Kenya is using a "five injection" regime, and whether that regime is only associated with the HCG vaccines and not usual tetanus vaccines.

Comment: The linked article has a lot of thundering denunciations about how the racist New World Order Illuminati want to destroy the population by sterilizing all women of childbearing age to get at their natural resources, but exactly *zero* links to any kind of evidence; the only other link to the article is a follow-up that the Kenyan Government is investigating the claim.

Comment: That one link does indicate that this question falls afoul of the "No claims that are currently being investigated" rule, though.

Comment: @Shadur: Is there any evidence, other than Lifesite News, that the Kenyan government actually is investigating? Lifesite could have made that up to add credence to their claim.

Comment: @nateeldredge [WaPo](http://www.washingtonpost.com/blogs/worldviews/wp/2014/11/14/the-tense-standoff-between-catholic-bishops-and-the-kenyan-government-over-tetanus-vaccines/) says they are. [Snopes says the story is bunk](http://www.snopes.com/medical/disease/tetanus.asp). Looks like the "proof" was manufactured by testing with wrong assumptions/wrong equipment. If no one has answered this by the time I get back from shoppping for groceries I might write it up more formally.

Comment: @Shadur: Thanks, the Washington Post link is very helpful background.  I agree with you that this claim is under official investigation and as such the question is premature, and I have raised the appropriate flag.  The question muddies the waters a bit by appearing to take it for granted that the vaccine actually contains HCG, whereas many people involved seem to think that this result was due to inappropriate testing.

Comment: Basic science kind of proves this is bunk. You can't have a vaccine that takes 3 years to work and then suddenly starts working.  And if one *could* produce antibodies to HCG, and HCG is produced during pregnancy, then why wouldn't every women produce antibodies to it after their first pregnancy?  If HCG was present it could, in theory, cause a miscarriage to someone currently pregnant at the time of the shot, but rendering them infertile from a single HCG dose just isn't plausible. (at worst a very few could develop cysts that effect fertility, but even that is generous assumption)

Answer (score 18):

Short answer: **No**.

Long answer:

First, as you may notice, the CCPLNS article does not reference any other news source aside from a follow-up on the same site saying that the Kenyan authorities are investigating.

If that doesn't make you suspicious right off the bat, you haven't been paying attention.

Second, let's google it, shall we?

[Google terms: "kenya investigating WHO tetanus vaccine"](https://www.google.nl/search?q=kenya%20investigating%20WHO%20tetanus%20vaccine&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=fflb&gfe_rd=cr&ei=1mhnVNHBJoivOt-PgdAK) sounds like it should cover things nicely. Let's see what we get...

- The [top](https://c-fam.org/turtle_bay/congress-should-investigate-tainted-tetanus-vaccine-sterilizing-kenyan-women/) [two](https://c-fam.org/turtle_bay/c-fam-exclusive-unicef-denies-giving-kenyan-women-birth-control-vaccine-without-knowledge/) hits are from C-Fam; the first is a loudly denouncing opinion piece that basically repeats the accusation several times and then treats them as fact while the second is an interview with UNICEF's chief of communications that denies the allegations in general and specifics.

Most salient point here:

> **C-Fam**: *Have you seen the test results of the tetanus vaccine from the
>   Kenya Catholic Doctors Association which found the tetanus vaccine
>   laced with hCG?*
>
> Elder: Yes. The tests were done in hospital laboratories in Kenya. The
>   staff in these laboratories could not however tell whether the samples
>   were vaccines or not, **as this was not declared to the testing
>   laboratories by the Catholic Doctors Association**. The laboratories
>   tested the samples for hCG using analyzers used for testing human
>   samples like blood and urine for pregnancy. There is no laboratory in
>   Kenya with the capacity to test non-human samples like vaccine for
>   hCG.

I'll get back to this in a bit.

- Then we get to a somewhat less biased source, the Washington Post, who has [this](http://www.washingtonpost.com/blogs/worldviews/wp/2014/11/14/the-tense-standoff-between-catholic-bishops-and-the-kenyan-government-over-tetanus-vaccines/) to say:

  - There *has* been an accusation made by the Kenya Conference of Catholic Bishops;
  - The Kenyan Health Ministry is denying the allegations, as are the WHO and UNICEF.
  - This isn't the first time the KCCB has made allegations like this regarding vaccines;
  - The KCCB claims to have proof, but KHM and the others are disputing the veracity:

> The science here is a little complex, but in short: Critics believe
>   that the vaccines contain the Beta-hCG hormone, which in high doses,
>   and administered in a particular way, may cause complications in
>   pregnancy.
>
> Both the bishops and health officials agree that if present, the
>   hormone has no business being in the vaccine doses. But it's unclear
>   whether the results of the tests ordered by the bishops are correct —
>   and if they are, whether the samples contain enough of the hormone to
>   have a contraceptive effect.
>
> Although the actual test results haven't been released to the public
>   by the bishops, the Catholic News Agency says it has seen a copy. And,
>   the wire service writes, while "copies of the lab results obtained by
>   CNA do show positive test results for the presence of the beta-hCG,
>   reference levels given on the lab reports show that levels present in
>   the vaccines **are within 'normal values' for healthy men and women."**
>
> UNICEF, which also says it's seen the results, added another note of
>   caution, arguing that **the labs testing the samples for the Catholic**
>   **groups were not informed that they were testing a vaccine** and used
>   "analyzers used for testing human samples like blood and urine for
>   pregnancy" to look for the presence of the hormone, which happens to
>   be the very same one detected by pregnancy tests.

The same point again.

This can be hard to explain to someone who doesn't have at least /some/ science grounding, but the principle at play here is that if you don't don't know what you're testing, the results are meaningless. It's like asking a vet to diagnose your pet and giving  him a verbal list of symptoms and "forgetting" to disclose whether you're talking about your Maine Coon cat or your Chiahuahua dog -- the same set of symptoms can have *wildly* different conclusions.

- Finally, there's a link to [Snopes](http://www.snopes.com/medical/disease/tetanus.asp) which does a more thorough job of debunking this than I can.

Comment: If you'd remove the [hostile and/or mocking responses to untenable claims](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/13/2703) you'd have more opportunity give better evidence of whether the claim is true or false. At the moment it's difficult to see what's actually "evidence" in your answer and what's just hand-wavy cries of outrage. FWIW I have *some* background (i.e. O-level) in chemistry but I can't confirm from my own experience whether your 2nd-last paragraph is true, and the fact that you have such an evident bias doesn't incline me towards trusting what you say as a matter of faith.

Comment: @ChrisW Fair enough. Stripped some of the more inflammatory language out. I was kind of cranky when I wrote it.

Comment: @ChrisW As for the "bad input yields useless conclusions" -- imagine being asked to carbon-date something without being told that it's actually a non-organic material. Chances are you'd wind up running useless tests with nonsensical results until and unless the penny drops and you realize you're not dealing with what you assumed you were handed...

Comment: @ChrisW in my specific example, a Maine Coon cat is large enough that the average human will need both arms to carry one. A Chihuahua fits in a ladies' purse and tends to be highly strung. If I were to report the heart rate for the latter over the phone to a vet that's assuming I'm talking about the former, the vet's going to conclude the poor cat is about one sudden loud noise away from either cardiac arrest or a berserk state...

Comment: I don't know whether the 'size' analogies are apt. Obviously with carbon-dating it's not just whether it's present that matters but how much. Is the same true of HCG in vaccines: that it's unremarkable find some, and that what matters is how much?

Comment: This is quite circumstantial reasoning and less a presentation of evidence, as required here. Snopes has some, but you just link to it. And then I'd consider any answer tackling this as incomplete if it doesn't deal with https://www.scirp.org/html/81838_81838.htm (The whole topic is making the rounds again, with 'science proved it' attached. Please upgrade your answer.)